# Using Element[]

Tags: functions

Can the Element[] function only be used for the domains given in the documentation?  I am trying to use it to determine if a value is contained in a previously defined list.  Thanks!

Comment: It only works for domains, yes. You might be interested in `MemberQ[]`...

Comment: Thanks.  That should do the trick

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question, now...

Comment: There is an exception to J.M.'s answer: [upvalues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html), although it would only be shorthand for `MemberQ[]`.

Comment: Difference is also that Element is a kind of assertion, you *tell* Mathematica that a given variable belongs to a given domain, whereas MemberQ is a *test*; you *ask* Mathematica whether a value is member of a list.

Answer (score 4):

There are as usual several ways. The most convenient one is probably [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html), as already pointed out in the comments.

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 9]
(* True *)
```

If you have a complex structure and not only a flat list, then [`FreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FreeQ.html) can be of use. Note that you have to negate the result.

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, {3}, {{4, 9}}}, 9]
Not[FreeQ[{1, 2, {3}, {{4, 9}}}, 9]]
(* False *)
(* True *)
```

Finally, note that you can specify the level where `MemberQ` should look for the appearance of the element

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, {3}, {{4, 9}}}, 9, Infinity]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but this dirty hack *might* be pretty fast IF you have to assess membership in a list of *symbolic* values with **no zeros**.

> ```
> symMemberQ[x_, mylist_] := SameQ[Times @@ Flatten[mylist /. x -> 0], 0]
> ```

Adding Flatten wil take care of nested list.

```
symMemberQ[e, {a, {b, g}, {d, {e, f}}}]
```

> ```
>    True
> ```

```
symMemberQ[w, {a, {b, g}, {d, {e, f}}}]
```

> ```
>    False
> ```

(It's a dirty hack, so beware: it might bite you).